# fprintf wont work with switch/case statement in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, printf

I have a simple C++ program to store pressed keys in file.
What works is `prinf` to show it in console but `fprintf` to save it in file won't work.
Even `fprintf(logx, "TEST");` works only when i delete while cycle.

My code:

```
int main(){
char c;
FILE *logx;

logx = fopen("mylog2.txt", "w");
fprintf(logx, "TEST");

while (true)
    {
    Sleep(10);
        for (int i = 8; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            {
                switch(i) {
                case 96:
                    fprintf(logx, "%d", 0);
                    break;
                case 97:
                    fprintf(logx, "%d", 1);
                    break;
                case 98:
                    fprintf(logx, "%d", 2);
                    break;
                case 99:
                    fprintf(logx, "%d", 3);
                    break;
                case 100:
                    fprintf(logx, "%d", 4);
                    break;
                case 101:
                    printf("%d", 5);
                    break;
                case 102:
                    printf("%d", 6);
                    break;
                case 103:
                    printf("%d", 7);
                    break;
                case 104:
                    printf("%d", 8);
                    break;
                case 105:
                    printf("%d", 9);
                    break;
                default:
                    c = char(i);
                    printf("%c", c);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

File is empty after pressing all possible numbers. Not even TEST is written in file (when while cycle is deleted "TEST" is printed).

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: Try to close the file, otherwise it remains opened and the writings may not appear. fclose(logx); should do the trick

Comment: @FrAxl93 Still not working.

Comment: 1. You should check whether `fopen` succeeded. 2. Output is typically buffered; you might want to explicitly flush your output with `fflush(logx)` (although `fclose(logx)` also would flush pending writes first).  If that still doesn't work, post your code that includes `fflush` and/or `fclose`.

Comment: If TEST is not printing, remove the rest of the code and figure out why. No point to the rest of the code until you know how to write TEST. Make absolutely certain you have the correct directory and are not writing to a mylog2.txt file somewhere else on your computer..

Comment: Thank i added flush and fclose well but what seems to help is to close program with X instead of red square stop in visual studio. When i close program with X everything is saved in file. When with stop nothing is saved and file is empty. Sorry if is beginner mistake.

Comment: Have you tried running the executable which is created by visual studio without actually using VS?

Comment: @FrAxl93 yes executable works fine. Solution is alredy before your question. Quitting program with X instead of visual studio STOP button. But dont know why.

Comment: And sorry guys fflush is working i just used it wrong before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must terminate the loop somehow. If you terminate your program with Ctrl-C the `FILE` I/O buffers will not be flushed and your file will be empty.

Alternatively you can put an `fflush(logx);` behind every individual `fprintf()` statement to force the data out to the file. But this is only a last resort as it makes file I/O very slow.

You should also close the file after the loop:

```
fclose(logx);
```

Comment: I put fflush(logx) at the end of for cycle. It works well thank you :)